# How to get difference between dates in the SAME column in oracle?

Tags: oracle11g

Hi This is my sample records:

id  id_store    id_member   order_number    id_devices  date_created
223240  2   6285849 84653349    2   8-May-14
1114344 2   6285849 84653349    2   8-May-14
5665565 2   6285849 84653349    50  28-Aug-14

I have many order_numbers having date_created difference i need which order_numbers having more than 3 months.

Please help me

Sreenivas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want list of order numbers that with duration of 3 months between the date_created.

```
select order_number, min(date_created), max(date_created), 
     max(date_created) - min(date_created) duration
from data_table
 group by order_number
having max(date_created) - min(date_created) > 120 /*number of days*/
```

you can simply use group by with order number and with having filter the duration.
I hope it is useful for you.